# Spark SQL not working for Hive 2.0

Tags: hive, apache-spark-sql

Environment:

- `spark-shell --master local`
- Spark version 2.x
- Hive version 2.x

After setting up Spark 2.0, I received "table not found" error when I tried `spark.sql` command. On the other, hand Hive is working fine.

So I researched a bit and found on Spark website that we need to have `hive-site.xml`, `hdfs.site.xml` and `core-site.xml` in `$SPARK_HOME/conf` directory. Moreover, I have also removed permissions for HDFS files to prevent any access issues.

So I did, but then I am getting following error message when I launch `spark-shell`. Please help me to understand why does it occur?

```
spark-shell --master local
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
17/05/31 23:38:57 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
17/05/31 23:39:00 WARN DataNucleus.General: Plugin (Bundle) "org.datanucleus.store.rdbms" is already registered. Ensure you dont have multiple JAR versions of the same plugin in the classpath. The URL "file:/root/spark/jars/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar" is already registered, and you are trying to register an identical plugin located at URL "file:/root/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar."
17/05/31 23:39:00 WARN DataNucleus.General: Plugin (Bundle) "org.datanucleus.api.jdo" is already registered. Ensure you dont have multiple JAR versions of the same plugin in the classpath. The URL "file:/root/spark/jars/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar" is already registered, and you are trying to register an identical plugin located at URL "file:/root/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar."
17/05/31 23:39:00 WARN DataNucleus.General: Plugin (Bundle) "org.datanucleus" is already registered. Ensure you dont have multiple JAR versions of the same plugin in the classpath. The URL "file:/root/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar" is already registered, and you are trying to register an identical plugin located at URL "file:/root/spark/jars/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar."
17/05/31 23:39:00 WARN metastore.HiveMetaStore: Retrying creating default database after error: Error creating transactional connection factory
javax.jdo.JDOFatalInternalException: Error creating transactional connection factory
        at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.NucleusJDOHelper.getJDOExceptionForNucleusException(NucleusJDOHelper.java:587)
        at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.freezeConfiguration(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:788)
        at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.createPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:333)
        at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:202)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at javax.jdo.JDOHelper$16.run(JDOHelper.java:1965)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invoke(JDOHelper.java:1960)
        at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invokeGetPersistenceManagerFactoryOnImplementation(JDOHelper.java:1166)
        at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:808)
        at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:701)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPMF(ObjectStore.java:365)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPersistenceManager(ObjectStore.java:394)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.initialize(ObjectStore.java:291)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.setConf(ObjectStore.java:258)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:76)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:136)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.<init>(RawStoreProxy.java:57)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.getProxy(RawStoreProxy.java:66)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.newRawStore(HiveMetaStore.java:593)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.getMS(HiveMetaStore.java:571)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB(HiveMetaStore.java:620)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:461)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.<init>(RetryingHMSHandler.java:66)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.getProxy(RetryingHMSHandler.java:72)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:5762)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:199)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.java:74)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1521)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.<init>(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:86)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:132)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:104)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:3005)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:3024)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getAllDatabases(Hive.java:1234)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.reloadFunctions(Hive.java:174)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.<clinit>(Hive.java:166)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:503)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.<init>(HiveClientImpl.scala:188)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader.createClient(IsolatedClientLoader.scala:264)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:358)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:262)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.<init>(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:66)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState$.org$apache$spark$sql$internal$SharedState$$reflect(SharedState.scala:166)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.<init>(SharedState.scala:86)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$sharedState$1.apply(SparkSession.scala:101)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$sharedState$1.apply(SparkSession.scala:101)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sharedState$lzycompute(SparkSession.scala:101)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sharedState(SparkSession.scala:100)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SessionState.<init>(SessionState.scala:157)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState.<init>(HiveSessionState.scala:32)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$.org$apache$spark$sql$SparkSession$$reflect(SparkSession.scala:978)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState$lzycompute(SparkSession.scala:110)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState(SparkSession.scala:109)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$getOrCreate$5.apply(SparkSession.scala:878)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$getOrCreate$5.apply(SparkSession.scala:878)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:99)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:99)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:230)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:40)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:99)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:878)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.createSparkSession(Main.scala:96)
        at $line3.$read$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:15)
        at $line3.$read$$iw.<init>(<console>:42)
        at $line3.$read.<init>(<console>:44)
        at $line3.$read$.<init>(<console>:48)
        at $line3.$read$.<clinit>(<console>)
        at $line3.$eval$.$print$lzycompute(<console>:7)
        at $line3.$eval$.$print(<console>:6)
        at $line3.$eval.$print(<console>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:786)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:1047)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:638)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:637)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:31)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.AbstractFileClassLoader.asContext(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:19)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest.loadAndRunReq(IMain.scala:637)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:569)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:565)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.interpretStartingWith(ILoop.scala:807)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.command(ILoop.scala:681)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.processLine(ILoop.scala:395)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply$mcV$sp(SparkILoop.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:37)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:37)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.beQuietDuring(IMain.scala:214)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.initializeSpark(SparkILoop.scala:37)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.loadFiles(SparkILoop.scala:105)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(ILoop.scala:920)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:909)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:909)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:97)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.process(ILoop.scala:909)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.doMain(Main.scala:69)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:743)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:187)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:212)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:126)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
NestedThrowablesStackTrace:
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry.createExecutableExtension(NonManagedPluginRegistry.java:631)
        at org.datanucleus.plugin.PluginManager.createExecutableExtension(PluginManager.java:325)
        at org.datanucleus.store.AbstractStoreManager.registerConnectionFactory(AbstractStoreManager.java:282)
        at org.datanucleus.store.AbstractStoreManager.<init>(AbstractStoreManager.java:240)
        at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager.<init>(RDBMSStoreManager.java:286)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry.createExecutableExtension(NonManagedPluginRegistry.java:631)
        at org.datanucleus.plugin.PluginManager.createExecutableExtension(PluginManager.java:301)
        at org.datanucleus.NucleusContext.createStoreManagerForProperties(NucleusContext.java:1187)
        at org.datanucleus.NucleusContext.initialise(NucleusContext.java:356)
        at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.freezeConfiguration(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:775)
        at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.createPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:333)
        at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:202)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at javax.jdo.JDOHelper$16.run(JDOHelper.java:1965)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invoke(JDOHelper.java:1960)
        at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invokeGetPersistenceManagerFactoryOnImplementation(JDOHelper.java:1166)
        at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:808)
        at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:701)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPMF(ObjectStore.java:365)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPersistenceManager(ObjectStore.java:394)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.initialize(ObjectStore.java:291)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.setConf(ObjectStore.java:258)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:76)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:136)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.<init>(RawStoreProxy.java:57)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.getProxy(RawStoreProxy.java:66)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.newRawStore(HiveMetaStore.java:593)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.getMS(HiveMetaStore.java:571)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB(HiveMetaStore.java:620)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:461)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.<init>(RetryingHMSHandler.java:66)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.getProxy(RetryingHMSHandler.java:72)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:5762)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:199)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.java:74)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1521)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.<init>(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:86)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:132)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:104)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:3005)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:3024)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getAllDatabases(Hive.java:1234)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.reloadFunctions(Hive.java:174)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.<clinit>(Hive.java:166)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:503)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.<init>(HiveClientImpl.scala:188)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader.createClient(IsolatedClientLoader.scala:264)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:358)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:262)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.<init>(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:66)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState$.org$apache$spark$sql$internal$SharedState$$reflect(SharedState.scala:166)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.<init>(SharedState.scala:86)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$sharedState$1.apply(SparkSession.scala:101)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$sharedState$1.apply(SparkSession.scala:101)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sharedState$lzycompute(SparkSession.scala:101)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sharedState(SparkSession.scala:100)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SessionState.<init>(SessionState.scala:157)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState.<init>(HiveSessionState.scala:32)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$.org$apache$spark$sql$SparkSession$$reflect(SparkSession.scala:978)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState$lzycompute(SparkSession.scala:110)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState(SparkSession.scala:109)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$getOrCreate$5.apply(SparkSession.scala:878)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$getOrCreate$5.apply(SparkSession.scala:878)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:99)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:99)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:230)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:40)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:99)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:878)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.createSparkSession(Main.scala:96)
        at $line3.$read$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:15)
        at $line3.$read$$iw.<init>(<console>:42)
        at $line3.$read.<init>(<console>:44)
        at $line3.$read$.<init>(<console>:48)
        at $line3.$read$.<clinit>(<console>)
        at $line3.$eval$.$print$lzycompute(<console>:7)
        at $line3.$eval$.$print(<console>:6)
        at $line3.$eval.$print(<console>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:786)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:1047)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:638)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:637)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:31)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.AbstractFileClassLoader.asContext(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:19)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest.loadAndRunReq(IMain.scala:637)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:569)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:565)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.interpretStartingWith(ILoop.scala:807)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.command(ILoop.scala:681)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.processLine(ILoop.scala:395)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply$mcV$sp(SparkILoop.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:37)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:37)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.beQuietDuring(IMain.scala:214)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.initializeSpark(SparkILoop.scala:37)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.loadFiles(SparkILoop.scala:105)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(ILoop.scala:920)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:909)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:909)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:97)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.process(ILoop.scala:909)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.doMain(Main.scala:69)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:743)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:187)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:212)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:126)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusException: Attempt to invoke the "BONECP" plugin to create a ConnectionPool gave an error : The specified datastore driver ("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver") was not found in the CLASSPATH. Please check your CLASSPATH specification, and the name of the driver.
        at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl.generateDataSources(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:259)
        at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl.initialiseDataSources(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:131)
        at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl.<init>(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:85)
        ... 146 more
Caused by: org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.connectionpool.DatastoreDriverNotFoundException: The specified datastore driver ("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver") was not found in the CLASSPATH. Please check your CLASSPATH specification, and the name of the driver.
        at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.connectionpool.AbstractConnectionPoolFactory.loadDriver(AbstractConnectionPoolFactory.java:58)
        at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.connectionpool.BoneCPConnectionPoolFactory.createConnectionPool(BoneCPConnectionPoolFactory.java:54)
        at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl.generateDataSources(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:238)
        ... 148 more
17/05/31 23:39:01 WARN DataNucleus.General: Plugin (Bundle) "org.datanucleus.store.rdbms" is already registered. Ensure you dont have multiple JAR versions of the same plugin in the classpath. The URL "file:/root/spark/jars/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar" is already registered, and you are trying to register an identical plugin located
```

Comment: What kind of Spark build did you install? Does it **explicitly** state that it was compiled **with Hive support**?

Comment: AFAIK the standard way to set up Spark against a Hadoop cluster is to define an env variable, typically in `$SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-env.sh`, as `export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/etc/hadoop/conf:/etc/hive/conf` *(or, if you are not running Spark on an Edge Node, create a specific dir, copy the Hadoop conf files there, and point the variable to that dir)*.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter.. I tried HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/etc/hadoop/conf:/etc/hive/conf and it worked! thanks!!